# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (35) : CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:51

Tags: python, pytorch, checkpointing

When I try to load a pytorch checkpoint:

```
checkpoint = torch.load(pathname)
```

I see:

> RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (35) : CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:51

I created the checkpoint with a GPU available, but now only have CPU available.

How do I load the checkpoint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the checkpoint data to the best currently available location:

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage.cuda()
else:
    map_location='cpu'

checkpoint = torch.load(pathname, map_location=map_location)
```